# Which tense to use in this example?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I have lied to someone about something, on one occassion, and I want to confess.

Should I say :"I have lied to you", or could I also say: "I have been lying to you", or is the latter only possible if the lying happened multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my opinion:

Normally you would say "I lied to you" or just "I lied", and then give the truth.  Or say "I lied about X", and they'll know the opposite is true. "I *have* lied to you" works, too, but it is a little different - it sounds a little more serious, in a way; like it is important, and you need to both sit down and have a heart-to-heart talk, for example.  Saying "I have" gives a sense of permanent change - that you now have this quality/status of being a liar, and your relationship is now different.  Another use case is the answer to Q:Have you ever lied to me? (A: I have lied to you.)

*I have been lying to you* is similar, but a little less permanent-sounding.  If you only lied once, you could still use it, but you are correct that they don't match well; don't use it if you just lied once and haven't had any interpersonal contact with the person since then.  Only allow the mismatch if you were with the person and had chances to admit that you told a lie.

Comment: "if you were with the person and had chances to admit that you told a lie." By this you mean over a period of time? So I haven't confessed  for a period of time?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  Primarily, to "have been lying" suggests saying multiple untrue things, or one untrue thing multiple times.  But simply neglecting to admit that you told a lie, given ample opportunity, would generally be considered sufficient.  In a legal setting, a lawyer might disagree.